# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException in GUI?

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception

I am beginner, I use java GUI, I don't understand why ther is an error. I have a `class Phong`(it is Frameclass) and `class LoaiPhong`. In `Phong` class, I get the error when I try to get a property in `LoaiPhong` class by method `GetItem5()` and `GetPop()`. However, `label( MainPanel.add(phongThuong[0].GetLabel()); )` runs well. So, why do I get the error???

```
public class Phong extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
         phongThuong[0] = new LoaiPhong();
         MainPanel.add(phongThuong[0].GetLabel());
         phongThuong[0].GetItem5().addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Time start:",
                  "Title", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
           }

      });
      phongThuong[0].GetPop().add(phongThuong[0].GetItem5());
   }
}
class LoaiPhong{
  private JMenuItem item5;
  private  JPopupMenu pop;
   LoaiPhong(){
      JMenuItem item5 = new JMenuItem("Move");
   }
   JPopupMenu GetPop(){
        return this.pop;
   }
   JMenuItem GetItem5(){
        return this.item5;
   }
}

error:
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at doanjava3.Phong.jButton1ActionPerformed(Phong.java:160)
    at doanjava3.Phong.access$000(Phong.java:32)
    at doanjava3.Phong$1.actionPerformed(Phong.java:81)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

UPDATE:
I tried to change `private JMenuItem item5`; to  `private JMenuItem item5=new JMenuItem("Move");` and  `private  JPopupMenu pop;` to `private  JPopupMenu pop = new JPopupMenu("option");` and it run well, what happed???? I think in contructor I have initialized `JMenuItem item5 = new JMenuItem("Move");` but why initialize it in property?

Comment: In which line is this exception thrown? Btw: please use Java code style: function names do not start with capital characters in Java.

Comment: `I don't understand why it error.` - the error message tells you. You have a variable on line 160 that contains a null value. So first figure out which variable is null and then figure out why it is null. We can't help because we have no idea what your methods do.

Comment: *and it run well* -- Because you actually initialized the values to non-null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reply this to your UPDATE:
It ran well, because u didn't initialized properly your variables at first. You just said `private JMenuItem item5` and then in constructor you said `JMenuItem item5=new JMenuItem("Move");` which is wrong, because you needed to remove `JMenuItem` keyword from your constructor, and let only `item5=new JMenuItem("Move");`
Try to initialize them in class constructor (good way), not outside constructor (bad way).

```
 class Phong()
 {
    private JMenuItem item5
    public Phong()
    {
         item5=new JMenuItem("Move");
    }
 }
```

And also try to implement `ActionListener` to your `Phong` class, and add unimplemented methods.

Comment: yes I see, but you needed to delete `JMenuItem` keyword from your class constructor

Comment: every time, when you want to initialize something, do it like I said in my answer. Try to compare what I wrote, with what you wrote, can you see any difference?